# Use Zapier to link a Customer's Xero account with our platform

Tags: zapier, xero-api, zapier-cli

I am trying to use Zapier to create an custom integration for customers

The main goal is to create a Xero Sales Invoice automatically once a Firestore document has been created.

I'm looking for Zapier to handle the whole thing (Even if takes some dev on my part)

Using a "Sign in Xero" button, I am struggling find out how I would auth a customer and then save the token on firetore and return them back to our website

Comment: It sounds to me like you could just create a simple 2 step zap:  "New Document Within a Firestore Collection in Firebase / Firestore" --> "Create Sales Invoice in Xero". Why do they need to sign into xero? All they have to do is create a new firestore doc under a connected account right?

Comment: We are just the platform. They would be creating an invoice on their Xero Account.